# How to correctly make an entry point to my module, which is containing multiple classess?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, module

I've started to develop a desktop app with node and electron. It has a package, which is implementing connection with some API. It is structured as one base class, and some derrived classes in this way:

- ApiBase
- ApiAuth extends ApiBase

  - ApiAuth.login()
  - ApiAuth.logout()
  - etc...
- ApiTasks extends ApiBase

  - ApiTasks.getTaskList()
  - etc...
- etc...

And now, i want to make nice and convinient way to use these classes in my app. So i need to create some entry point, which will provide an access to my API implementation. But, i do not have much expirience to make it right.

I thought about something like this:

*index.js:*

```
const ApiAuth = require('./amazing-time-api-auth');
const ApiTasks = require('./amazing-time-api-tasks');

apiAuth = new ApiAuth('www.sample-host.com');
apiTasks = new ApiTasks('www.sample-host.com');

module.exports = {
  login: apiAuth.login,
  logout: apiAuth.logout,
  getTaskList: apiTasks.getTaskList,
  etc...
}
```

*somwhere at the app:*

```
const api = require("./lib/someApi");

// need to get task list for some reason

api.getTaskList(param1, param2)
```

But there are some problems with this approach i managed:

- it is a problem to pass host param to the constructors in index.js dynamicly
- i am not sure if creating this instances everytime requiring index.js is a rigth thing

So i want to know about some approches i can use here, because i do now even know where to start research. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you identified some of the most crucial decisions with this:

**it is a problem to pass host param to the constructors in index.js dynamicly**

IMO Configuration and the interface are important considerations.  Even though it can be refactored after the fact an easy to configure and consume interface will help reduce adoption of your library.  As you pointed out the configuration is static right now and very brittle.  Ie a change to the URL will cascade to all clients and require all clients to update.

A first intuitive alternative may be to allow dynamic configuration of the current structure:

```
apiAuth = new ApiAuth(process.env.API_AUTH_URL || 'www.sample-host.com');
apiTasks = new ApiTasks(process.env.API_TASKS_URL || 'www.sample-host.com');
```

While this allows client to dynamically configure the URL, the configuration is "implicit".  IMO this is unintuitive and difficult to document.  Also it's not explicit and requires a client to look in the code to see the environmental variables and instantiation flow.

I would favor exposing these classes to the client directly.  I would consider this approach "explicit" as it forces the client to explicitly configure/instantiate your components.  I think it's like providing your clients with primitives and allowing them to compose, build, and configure them in whatever way they want:

```
const ApiAuth = require('./amazing-time-api-auth');
const ApiTasks = require('./amazing-time-api-tasks');

module.exports = {
  auth: ApiAuth,
  tasks: ApiTasks
}
```

This automatically namespaces the api behind its functions (auth|tasks) AND requires that the client instantiatae the classes before using:

```
const api = require("./lib/someApi");
const auth = new api.auth(process.env.SOMETHING, 'some-url');
```

This pulls the [configuration further out in the architecture.](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) It forces the client to decide how it wants to get the URL and explicitly instantiate the library.  What if one of your clients doesn't use login/logout? This may be more flexible in that case.

**i am not sure if creating this instances everytime requiring index.js is a rigth thing**

If instantiation should remain hidden, another alternative would be to provide a builder function in order to encapsulate it:

```
const ApiAuth = require('./amazing-time-api-auth');
const ApiTasks = require('./amazing-time-api-tasks');

apiAuth = new ApiAuth('www.sample-host.com');
apiTasks = new ApiTasks('www.sample-host.com');

module.exports = {
  auth: {
     build: (url) => {
        return new ApiAuth(url);
     }
  },
  tasks: {
    build: (url) => {
       return new ApiTasks(url);
    }
  }
}
```

This should still hide each class but still allows the client to decide how it configures each class:

```
const api = require("./lib/someApi");
const auth = api.auth.build('my-url');
auth.login();
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, sir!